# How can I normalize data field in Access that has comma delimited values

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

This seems to be a common question, yet I can't seem to get the answer.

A table which I read out using VBA from an excel file contains one field that has multiple values separated by a comma delimiter. I know the proper way to do this is to normalize this field. I can't seem to get my solution to work though.

My table looks something like this:

```
ProdID | Color | Value
1      | Blue, Green | 30
2      | White, Blue, Red | 50
3 etc.
```

I am trying to split the values by first putting them in a temp table and then updating the main one, but that seems cumbersome, and I suspect there must be a much more intelligent solution to this...

```
    'check that data is available and copy data to new temporary sheet
rowCount = wks.UsedRange.Rows.count
If rowCount < 2 Then
    MsgBox ("The Workbook " & wkb & " contains no Data. The Process will not continue to execute!")
    GoTo EndCleanUp
Else
    'delete old data in DB table
    With tblMorningstarFS
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
        DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE * FROM " & .Name
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    End With
    'create array with prod color id set
    Dim tempArray()
    ReDim tempArray(rowCount, 1)
    With wks
        For i = 0 To rowCount
        tempArray(i, 0) = .Cells(i + 1, 1) '  prodID

        tempArray(i, 1) = .Cells(i + 1, 2) ' colorID
        Next i
    End With
    'create temporary table
    curDatabase.Execute "CREATE TABLE tempColorTable " _
        & "(ProdID CHAR, ColorID CHAR);"
    'fill prodID/colorID table with array info
    With curDatabase.OpenRecordset("tempColorTable", dbOpenTable)
        For i = 1 To UBound(tempArray, 1) + 1
            .AddNew
            rs.Fields("ProdID") = wks.Range("A" & i + 1).Value
            rs.Fields("ColorID") = wks.Range("C" & i + 1).Value
            rs.Update
        Next i
    End With
    'update the exisiting table with information
    Dim SQL As String
    SQL = "INSERT INTO tblProd_Color ( ProdID, ColorID ) " & _
    "SELECT tempColorTable.ProdID, tempColorTable.ColorID " & _
    "FROM tempColorTable"
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
    'fill prod table with value information
    With wks
        For i = 1 To rowCount
            rs.AddNew
            rs.Fields("PRODUCT") = .Range("A" & i + 1).Value
            rs.Fields("VALUE") = .Range("C" & i + 1).Value
            rs.Update
        Next i
    End With


    With wks
        For i = 1 To rowCount
            rs.AddNew
            rs.Fields("PRODUCT") = .Range("A" & i + 1).Value
            rs.Fields("VALUE") = .Range("C" & i + 1).Value
            rs.Update
        Next i
    End With
End If
```

This code doesn't fully work yet, but before I invest the time to make it work, I wanted to know if I am at least on the right track.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same situation.
I used [HeaderTable<---DetailTable] Structure  to solve the issue by doing the following steps.

```
1. Created a Header table that stores all the "Header Data", in your case ProdID,Value

2. Created a table containing "Detail Data" in your case ProdID,RowNo,Color

3. Insert all Row's ProdID into Header Table
4. Split the values in  the field Color based on index of (,)Comma. For each Substring insert a row into Detail table with ProdID,RowNo,Substring as color.
```

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar to your answer. Thanks for your input!